# How to download a local file with javascript function

Tags: javascript

What is the best and fastest way to download a local file with javascript function:

I have a button once clicked should launch the download process, I am trying to use javacript to handle this but it is not working !!!!

here is the code:  the function receives the file name as parameter and the path is static:

```js
function downloadFile(filename) {
  var filePath = "C:\\LangsDirectory\\Test\\" + filename;
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  downloadLink.href = uri;
  downloadLink.download = filePath;
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `download` attribute does not work on cross-origin URLs and all `file:` scheme URLs are considered cross-origin.

The only way I can see to do this would be to use a file `<input>` to have the user select the file, then read it with JavaScript, generate a Blob from it, and then set up a download for that.

I wouldn't bother. The file is already local. The user can move or copy it to wherever they like using their normal file manager.